# "Eigen"-like problem for rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is to find all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ for which

$$
A x = \lambda B x
$$

with $A, B \in \mathrm{M}(m, n, \mathbb{C})$ being $m \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ with $m < n$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Further, $\mathrm{rank}(A) = \mathrm{rank}(B) = m$.

I wonder, if this is a well known problem and if there is a good way to express/determine all solutions. Thanks a lot in advantage!

---

Some thoughts: 
For instance, one could define $V_0 := \mathrm{null}(A) \cap \mathrm{null}(B)$ and assume that for every solution $x_s$, there exists a solution space $X_s := x_s \cup V_o$. If there exists more than one linearly independent solution, then all the solutions can be expressed as a set of solution spaces $\left\{ X_i \right\}$ as a linear combination of two solutions $x_i, x_j$ does not necessarily have to be also a solution. But how to determine the $x_i$?

If one defines $V_+^A$ as the orthognal complement to $\mathrm{null}(A)$ and $V_+^B$ analoguously, one could first determine a solution to

$$
A V_+^A \sigma_+ = \lambda B V_+^B \tau_+ \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad (B V_+^B)^{-1} A V_+^A \sigma_+ = \lambda \tau_+
$$

with $\sigma_+, \tau_+ \in \mathbb{C}^m$. With this relationship and by defining $C := (B V_+^B)^{-1} A V_+^A$, $V_0^A := \mathrm{null}(A)$ and $V_0^B$ analoguously, one can determine

$$
x = \begin{pmatrix}
V_+^A & V_0^A
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_+ \\ \sigma_0
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
V_+^B & V_0^B
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda\tau_+ \\ \tau_0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
V_0^B & -V_0^A
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\tau_0 \\ \sigma_0
\end{pmatrix}
=
(V_+^A - V_+^BC)\sigma_+
$$

with $\sigma_0, \tau_0 \in \mathbb{C}^{(n - m)}$. Assuming, what was done is correct, one should get a space of solutions to $x$ for each $\sigma_+$. But I think, this is more confusing than needed.

Maybe, there are some ways to determine the solutions using the SVD or other approaches. The problem could also be expressed as a system of polynomial equations, but then - for arbitrary $A, B$ - this could end up in an $\mathrm{NP}$-hard problem (couldn't it?) and I really don't think, that this has to be.

(Please excuse possible errors. Thank you all)